# If CALayer's display calls UIView's drawRect, then why is drawRect called more often?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, calayer

From what I understand so far, when is UIView's `drawRect` called?  It is called by CALayer's `display` calling `drawInContext` or `drawLayer:InContext`, and then calling `UIView`'s `drawRect`.

But at the same time, I understand that `drawRect` is called more often than `display`, for example, when the app starts up, `drawRect` is called, but `display` is not, so we need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the layer for it to be drawn.

But these two ideas conflict with each other: if `drawRect` is called by `display` indirectly (through `drawInContext` or `drawLayer:InContext`), then whenever `drawRect` is called, `display` should also be invoked already.  So, following this logic, `display` is called at least as often as `drawRect`, but what is wrong with this picture?